# Check if Python has written the targeted text

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm writing a code to scrape selected portions of visible text off a great number of web pages. Here's a part of it:

```
                divTag = soup.find_all("div", {'id':'articleBody'})
                for tag in divTag:
                    pTags = tag.find_all("p") 
                    for tag in pTags:
                        print >>f, tag.text
```

**How can I check if Python has found and written the targeted text**, and put the link aside (to a list) if the scraping wasn't a success?

I didn't find an answer here, and I don't know where to look in the documentation.

Comment: Umm... how about "check if Python has found (and written) the targeted text"?

Comment: One option would be to add if statement to check whether you parsed the item correctly and use Python built in logging module to log the success/failure.I have also successfully used tinydb package to store results and failures. Big advantage of that library is simple syntax, quite powerful querying and its very lightweight (stores data as json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternative to know if python found the text you are looking for:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.google.com']
for i in range(len(urls)):
    r = requests.get(urls[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('p')
    for item in items:
        if "2016 - Privacidad - Condiciones" in item.text:
            print "Python has found the targeted text"
```

If python doesn't find the `text`, you need to use `remove()` method.

Comment: Nice solution.
If item.text contains any character, it means Python found something in the tags I selected.